# How to update form with get approval from another specific user in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to create a basic approval system in my Django project. In this system there are several ranks, but for this question I only use `Lead` and `Manager`. I created `forms` and this forms are representing `limits`.

Only `Lead` can fill these forms. But what I want is when a Lead update the form it shouldn't display without `Manager`'s approval. How can I do that?

**approvals/models.py**

```
class DoaTable(models.Model):
    LIMITS = (
        ('Low Risk', 'Low Risk'),
        (...),
        ('Strict Credit Check', 'Strict Credit Check'),
        ('No Credit Check', 'No Credit Check'),
    )

    RANKS = (
        ('Analyst', 'Analyst'),
        ('Senior Analyst', 'Senior Analyst'),
        ('Lead', 'Lead'),
        ('Manager', 'Manager'),
        ('...Officer'),
    )
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=RANKS)
    risk = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=LIMITS)
    limit = models.FloatField()
    comp_name = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**user/models.py**

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

...
password = models.CharField(max_length=250)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
rank = models.CharField(max_length=200)
...

class Rank(models.Model):
    rank_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=False)
```

Ranks in this model is same as Doa table ranks. We assume that user ranks are Lead and Manager for this scenerio.

**approvals/forms.py**

```
class DoaTableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DoaTable
        fields = ('rank', 'risk', 'limit',)

class UpdateDoaTableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DoaTable
        fields = ('limit',)
```

**aprovals/views.py**

```
def update_limit(request, id):
    limiting = get_object_or_404(DoaTable, id=id)
    form = UpdateDoaTableForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=limiting)
    limiting_item = DoaTable.objects.filter(id=id)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('approvals:update_limit_list')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'limiting_item': limiting_item
    }

    return render(request, 'limitUpdate.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **1. How to do it with your current architecture**

Add a new column to your DoaTable model to reflect whether it should be displayed or not and only display it in your view if doatable.should_display is `True`:

**approvals/models.py**

```
class DoaTable(models.Model):
    # ....
    should_display = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=RANKS)
    # ...
```

Then override your ModelForm's `__init__()` to accept the current user and `clean()` method to check for the rank:

**approvals/forms.py**

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
# ...
class UpdateDoaTableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DoaTable
        fields = ('limit',)

    def __init__(self, *args, user, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if self.user.rank != "Lead": # BAD: hardcoded value
            raise ValidationError(
                    "You do not have the required rank."
            )
        return cleaned_data # Always return the cleaned data
```

Pass in the `request.user` in your view:

**approvals/views.py**

```
def update_limit(request, id):
    # ...
    form = UpdateDoaTableForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, user=request.user, instance=limiting)
    # ...
```

### **2. Suggested ways of doing it**

1. `AbstractUser` comes in with groups and permissions which you can utilize to check if your user belongs to a certain [group](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.groups) or [has](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perms) a certain [permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.user_permissions) before doing an action (in this case updating/approving forms), for example permissions could be: 'fill_form_perm', 'approve_form_perm' and your groups could be: 'lead', 'officer'.
2. You can make use of [IntegerChoices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) for the ranks in your model then check the level of permission your user has by a doing a simple comparison. This is more flexible as you can chain in multiple ranks, for example below Manager but above Senior Anaylist in one condition without too much of a hassle.